# Writing in another file with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php script (just for calculation) and a html file. Let's say the php file has finished its calculation and the solution is 10. The following line is in the body of the just mentioned html file:

```
<div id="here"></div>
```

Now I want the php file to write the 10 into the html. I thought of adding a few lines of javascript at the end of the php to make the job. The question is if this is even possible with something like (index.html).getElementById(here).innerHTML or something. Both files are in the same folder and setting the proper permission shouldn't be a problem.

I know I could put everything in one file but this is part of a bigger project. I just adapted my problem on this simple example to avoid that you need to read plenty of lines.

Comment: Use AJAX!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: So the php will contain a javascript which sends the 10 to the html. But how does the code which receives the 10 in the html look like? I can't convert the html to a php becaue this won't work with the rest of my application. The only idea would be to add AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html to the htaccess.

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) to see how jQuery AJAX is used to populate an HTML element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Script should look like this to get response from PHP

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "yourphp.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Hope this solves your problem
ref: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp

Comment: Thanks. But in this case I have to save this file as .php, don't I? As I mentioned in the comment to the first answer I can^t do this because this wouln't work with the rest of my system. There is no chance to adapt everything.

Comment: I didn't know javascript can receive and send via Ajax. I was always wondering why some Ajax tutorials use xhttp and other the ajax() function. I will have another look and try to implement the javascript code into my html to reiceve and send data with Ajax. Thanks!

Comment: Ajax is a JavaScript technique. It is essentially JavaScript. You can either use jQuery or plain OLD JavaScript. watch this video: https://youtu.be/_iRIPJHrdXg and other parts related to it.

Comment: One last question without having tried this. The html file will loaded. After a click on a button the php will be called to do the calculation. When its done it sends for example a 10 back to the html via Ajax. Will the javascript in the html page receive and write the 10 in the "here" element automatically? Is it enough to add onload to the script part in the html file?

Comment: if your PHP is sending plain text...yes, it will write plain text.... if your php is sending JSON...you will need to parseJSON.....also watchout for XML.....look at this one http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php (dont get confused at it uses jquery....look at how responses are being handled)

Comment: I probably didn't ask clearly, sorry. I meant if the index.html is loaded will its javascript (which receives the 10 and writes it in the html part) automatically stay ready and wait until my php sends something?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean...but when you make REQUEST you get RESPONSE. how and when you want to MAKE REQUEST depends on you....you should definitely check out http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ it is more clearer than what I can offer you..

Answer (score -3):

PHP is server-side and Javascript is client-side. I don't recommend you to use embedded PHP but you should take a look at Ajax Requests.
[Here's some documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)